# clicked radio button value is displayed as undefined

Tags: jquery

The result is shown as undefined for the value of radio button being clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio").change(function(){
        checkResult(this);
    }); 
});
function checkResult(el)
{
    var clicked=$('el:checked');
    var clickedvalue=clicked.val();
    alert(clickedvalue);
    $this=$(el).parent("div.QA");
    $this.slideUp();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *not* using the DOM element in your selector. **Your selector $('el:checked') means that you are looking for el tag that is checked.**

*Change*

```
var clicked=$('el:checked');
```

*To*

```
var isChecked= el.is(':checked');
```

Your code changes accordingly

```
function checkResult(el)
{
  var clicked= $(el);
  var clickedvalue=clicked.val();
  alert(clickedvalue);
  $this=$(el).parent("div.QA");
  $this.slideUp();
  var isChecked= el.is(':checked');
}
```

Comment: ooh i was selecting the DOM element before not the one that is being clicked so .is what am missing right helped

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the el parameter when fetching the value.

Try this:

```
clickedvalue = $(el).val();
```

Comment: the clicked variable has an object and u r not referencing that,and its not working like this

Comment: actually we can directly get the value without first getting which value was clicked i mean var clicked not needed in my code